# No. of channels in the unet module - PyTorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, image-segmentation

I try to design a unet model for RGB images(3channels) and  also need a model for grayscale image .
I got a code for pytorch and it is working. But I couldn't understand whether this model takes 3 input channels or combining 3?
How can we design a model with 3 encoder and 3 decoder which are parallel and combines at the output layer?
Which variable is for num_channels?

The code for UNET model  .

```
  **class UNet(Module):
    def __init__(self, encChannels=(3, 16, 32, 64), decChannels=(64, 32, 16),nbClasses=1,retainDim=True,outSize=(config.INPUT_IMAGE_HEIGHT,  config.INPUT_IMAGE_WIDTH)):
      super().__init__()
      # initialize the encoder and decoder
      self.encoder = Encoder(encChannels)
      self.decoder = Decoder(decChannels)
      # initialize the regression head and store the class variables
      self.head = Conv2d(decChannels[-1], nbClasses, 1)
      self.retainDim = retainDim
      self.outSize = outSize


def forward(self, x):
    # grab the features from the encoder
    encFeatures = self.encoder(x)
    # pass the encoder features through decoder making surethat
    # their dimensions are suited for concatenation
    decFeatures = self.decoder(encFeatures[::-1][0],
        encFeatures[::-1][1:])
    # pass the decoder features through the regression head to
    # obtain the segmentation mask
    map = self.head(decFeatures)
    # check to see if we are retaining the original output
    # dimensions and if so, then resize the output to matchthem
    if self.retainDim:
        map = F.interpolate(map, self.outSize)
    # return the segmentation map
    return map**
class Block(Module):
def __init__(self, inChannels, outChannels):
    super().__init__()
    # store the convolution and RELU layers
    self.conv1 = Conv2d(inChannels, outChannels, 3)
    self.relu = ReLU()
    self.conv2 = Conv2d(outChannels, outChannels, 3)
def forward(self, x):
    # apply CONV => RELU => CONV block to theinputsand returnit
    return self.conv2(self.relu(self.conv1(x)))

class Encoder(Module):
    def __init__(self, channels=(3, 16, 32, 64)):
        super().__init__()
        # store the encoder blocks and maxpooling layer
        self.encBlocks = ModuleList(
            [Block(channels[i], channels[i + 1])
                for i in range(len(channels) - 1)])
        self.pool = MaxPool2d(2)
    def forward(self, x):
        # initialize an empty list to store the intermediate outputs
        blockOutputs = []
        # loop through the encoder blocks
        for block in self.encBlocks:
            # pass the inputs through the current encoder block, store
            # the outputs, and then apply maxpooling on the output
            x = block(x)
            blockOutputs.append(x)
            x = self.pool(x)
        # return the list containing the intermediate outputs
        return blockOutputs



class Decoder(Module):
    def __init__(self, channels=(64, 32, 16)):
        super().__init__()
        # initialize the number of channels, upsampler blocks, and
        # decoder blocks
        self.channels = channels
        self.upconvs = ModuleList(
            [ConvTranspose2d(channels[i], channels[i + 1], 2, 2)
                for i in range(len(channels) - 1)])
        self.dec_blocks = ModuleList(
            [Block(channels[i], channels[i + 1])
                for i in range(len(channels) - 1)])
    def forward(self, x, encFeatures):
        # loop through the number of channels
        for i in range(len(self.channels) - 1):
            # pass the inputs through the upsampler blocks
            x = self.upconvs[i](x)
            # crop the current features from the encoder blocks,
            # concatenate them with the current upsampled features,
            # and pass the concatenated output through the current
            # decoder block
            encFeat = self.crop(encFeatures[i], x)
            x = torch.cat([x, encFeat], dim=1)
            x = self.dec_blocks[i](x)
        # return the final decoder output
        return x
    def crop(self, encFeatures, x):
        # grab the dimensions of the inputs, and crop the encoder
        # features to match the dimensions
        (_, _, H, W) = x.shape
        encFeatures = CenterCrop([H, W])(encFeatures)
        # return the cropped features
        return encFeatures
```

I wish my problem can be solved by modifying the code .
Thank you

Comment: `Encoder` and `Decoder` is defined somewhere else, receiving feature dimensions including an input channel dimension.
It seems that `self.decoder` has 2 decoders and the last decoder is `self.haed`.
U-Net skip connection is performed by passing encoder's layer-wise output feature to the decoder.

Comment: updated the encoder and decoder functions. can u help me to write the code as a function ?

Comment: when the forward () works?

Comment: forward(self,x)